# How to store Multiple categories in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I’m working on a C# project for a class and my assignment is to make a forms app that looks like the Carvana website. For instance, if the user picks Nissan only Nissan cars come up and if you change the body type to trucks only Nissan trucks show up. Also, each model has additional information about them such as the truck is 4-wheel drive, etc. I was going to use a jagged array, but I don’t think that’s the best way so I’m kind of stuck.
Thank you for any help

So far I have only used arrays and I tried Enums for the makes and that works for what I wanted to use them for. Also I'm using combo boxes for the pull-down menu

Comment: An easy way is to use a database and then search the database for what you need. Then bind the query results to the output column. Saranga's suggestion is also very useful, have you tried it? Do you have any updates?

Comment: If you consider a Jagged array, it means you do not have a class to describe each car with properties for the attributes you want to filter by. Step one is to create a data model for your products, and then ask a specific question. Keep in mind that SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in an [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/read-xml-data-from-url) or [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) object.
Easy to append. Easy to search.

If you want to stick with something similar you are already using, You better use an object [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Please always consider links in your answer as if they were broken the moment you post. Your answer should have enough detail without the links. Your answer currently suggests using XML or JSON, but doesn't show how. It suggests that they are easy to append and search but doesn't show how. And it assumes that the OP knows about dictionaries. You should fill in the missing detail.